# How to say “I played well”?

Tags: grammar, nuances, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

How would you say “I played well”?
I wrote **よく　遊びました** , which is **よい** *(good)* in the adverb form and then **遊ぶ** *(to play)* in polite past but the translation comes out as “I played a lot”. What am i doing wrong?

Also, do y’all recommend any particular app for japanese translations?

Comment: Played well in what context? An instrument? A sport? A video game? All three would use different verbs

Comment: @Angelos a sport

Comment: The first part of your question is fine, but resource requests are off-topic.  You can refer to our [Resource Thread](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/78).

Comment: FYI, よく遊んだ is a perfectly natural sentence if you mean "I had a lot of fun (e.g., at an amusement park or playing a video game)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, よい is an adjective already. I can see you tried to make it an adverb by adding く、but the adverb よく means often when used with 遊【あそ】ぶ in a sentence.

Secondly, the word 遊【あそ】ぶ on its own usually means play as in "kids play" kind of play. So you need a more specific verb other than 遊【あそ】ぶ if that’s not the case, but if you want to say you played well (as in nicely) with other kids, you would say something like 仲【なか】良【よ】く　遊【あそ】んだ。

If you mean play, as in "played the piano", then you’d say ピアノが　上手【うま】く　(or 上手【じょうず】に)　弾【ひ】けた。

You could say 〜が上手【うま】くいった ("〜 went well") instead, then you could add pretty much anything you do, such as: 野球【やきゅう】が上手【うま】くいった, or ゲームが上手【うま】くいった, or even デートが上手【うま】くいった！

Comment: As a side note, the verb for "playing" something (a game or a sport) is usually やる. Like ゲームをやる or 野球をやる. So you could also say よくやった！ in pretty much all contexts, if not considering formality of speech. Also, よくできた is also a VERY common expression for "well done", either to compliment someone else or something to say to self.

Comment: I'm sure you all know this emoji ?  On iOS and macOS (idk about other platforms), the text on there is 大変よくできました, and this emoji is a stamp a teacher would stamp on a student's homework or test when the student performs excellently. よくできた is just a casual form of the same sentence.